# PyQGIS optimize for loop in QGIS script for better performance

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis

I have a question regarding a for loop that I wrote in a QGIS Python script. The loop works, but it takes too long since I need to let it run over millions of points. So I’m looking for some advice how to improve the coding and hence the performance of the for loop.

The script works as follows: Before the for loop, it takes a point vector layer and writes the points in a point list `Pointlist`. The for loop over the point list starts: for every point, a viewshed is calculated. The resulting viewshed raster is then loaded in a numpy array and some weighting over clases is done. After that, the sum of the viewshed is calculated. At the end of the loop, the coordinates and the resulting sum are written in a list. The list gets writen outside the for loop (initially the results were written in the result CSV inside the loop, but I thought it is faster outside the loop?).

The script part with the for loop looks like this:

```
import processing
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.utils import *
from qgis.gui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
import gdalnumeric
import numpy
import csv
import os
import time
import datetime

# viewshed analysis for every point in Pointlist (from Regular Points Grid)
# output is a csv-file with point coordinate and count of viewed pixel

pointgrid_clip = "path_to_my_input_Raster.tif"

inlayer = QgsVectorLayer(pointgrid_clip, "", "ogr")
iter = inlayer.getFeatures()
Pointlist = [f.geometry().asPoint() for f in iter]
totalPoints = len(Pointlist)

Punktliste = []
Coordliste = []
gew_list =[3,2,1,3,2,1]

LoadFile = gdalnumeric.LoadFile
now = datetime.datetime.now

for point in Pointlist:
    n = n-1
    start = now()
    coordstr = '%d,%d' % (point.x(),point.y() )
    extent_viewshed = "%s,%s,%s,%s" % (str(point.x()-(Sichtweite-(pixelWidth/2))), str(point.x()+(Sichtweite-(pixelWidth/2))), str(point.y()-(Sichtweite+(pixelWidth/2))), str(point.y()+(Sichtweite+(pixelWidth/2))))
    viewshed = processing.run("grass7:r.viewshed", 
                            {'input':dgm_repclip_ausschluss['OUTPUT'],
                            'coordinates':coordstr,
                            'observer_elevation':Hoehe_Anlage,
                            'target_elevation':1.5,
                            'max_distance':str(Sichtweite),
                            'refraction_coeff':0.14286,
                            'memory':4000,
                            '-c':False,
                            '-r':False,
                            '-b':False,
                            '-e':False,
                            'output':Output_view + "/" + coordstr + "_viewshed.tif",
                            'GRASS_REGION_PARAMETER':extent_viewshed,
                            'GRASS_REGION_CELLSIZE_PARAMETER':0,
                            'GRASS_RASTER_FORMAT_OPT':'',
                            'GRASS_RASTER_FORMAT_META':''})
    raster_file = LoadFile(viewshed['output'])
    werteliste = [w for w in raster_file.flat if not numpy.isnan(w)]
    erg = numpy.histogram(werteliste, bins=[66.1,74.1,82.1,90.1,98.1,106.1,114.1])
    s = (erg[0]*gew_list)
    pixel_count = s.sum()
    Coordliste.append(coordstr)
    Punktliste.append(str(pixel_count))
    ende = now()
    dauer = ende - start
    restdauer = totalPoints * dauer
    feedback.setProgressText('Prozessdauer: ' + str(dauer) + ', verbleibende Zeit~ ' + str(restdauer)  + ', verbleibende Rechnungen: '  + str(n))

os.chdir(Output_Results)
rows = zip(Coordliste,Punktliste)
with open("viewshed_count.csv", 'wt') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar=',')
    for row in rows:
        writer.writerow(row)
```

Comment: Isnt `r_viewshed` whats taking a long time to run? Pick fewer Points, lower DEM resolution, max distance etc.

Comment: Hey @BERA, 
yes indeed it is, but I managed to reduce the runtime of every loop from ~6 to ~5 seconds by simply putting LoadFile = gdalnumeric.LoadFile and now = datetime.datetime.now outside the loop!

Comment: So my question is optimization "besides the r.viewshed” ;)

Comment: There's no point optimising beyond the r.viewshed function until you know how much time that function is taking. If its taking 99% of the loop you're not going to get any speed tweaking the rest. You know how to use python time functions now its an opportunity to up your "code profiling" skills!

Comment: What is slow now then?